# Looping through matrix multiplication R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I’ve provided a small example dataset but my real dataset is much larger.

I'm working with two matrices, and the number of columns in mat_1 is always equal to the number of rows in mat_2.

```
mat_1 <- matrix(c(5,6,11,1,7,8), nrow = 2, ncol=3)
mat_2 <- matrix(c(1,2,9,8,4,5,11,7,6), nrow = 3, ncol=3)
```

I’d like to multiply each row sequentially in mat_1 (so each row would be a 1x3 ‘mini-matrix’) with each column in mat_2 (each column would be 3x1 ‘mini matrix’), so that I end up with a 2x3 matrix like this:

```
       [1]  [2]  [3]
 [1]   90   119  174
 [2]   80   92   121
```

I feel R will have a cleverer solution to this than a loop.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it from a matrix to a data frame earlier in the day and completely forgot. Lesson learned. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just multiplication of two conformable matrices right? That is done in R with the  %*% operand.

`mat_1 %*% mat_2` gives your output:

```
> mat_1%*%mat_2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   90  119  174
[2,]   80   92  121
```

Comment: I’m…going to go and hide in a cupboard now. 

I’ve just realised it wasn’t working because I had my large dataset set as a data frame, but I should have had the knowledge and confidence to know that should have worked, and looked into it further. 

I’m completely mortified, but thank you for your help.